# Swipe between Spaces/full-screen apps: Uniform gestures for Multi-Touch Trackpad and Magic Mouse

Tags: mouse, magic-trackpad, bettertouchtool, gesture

I often run macOS apps in system provided full-screen mode. I switch between using an Apple Magic Mouse and MacBook's Multi-Touch Trackpad.

To switch between Spaces/full-screen apps, System Preferences allow me to use 3 or 4 finger swiping on the Multi-Touch Trackpad, but only 2 finger swipe on the Magic Mouse.

I would like to have the same gesture available for both the devices. I don't want to think about what tool I'm using. To me it should just be the same.

Is there a way to do this using [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai)? I haven't been able to figure out the correct action?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it with BetterTouchTool. In BetterTouchTool the action is called "move right/left a space.

I set up an action for both 2 finger swipe left, and 2 finger swipe right on the trackpad and left the magic mouse with the standard 2 finger swipe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use BetterTouchTool to define matching gestures to swipe between Spaces running full-screen apps.

Simply select the appropriate device in the toolbar, then click on the `+` button in the first column under **Groups & Top Level Triggers** to select the gesture. Then after selecting the trigger in the first column, select the appropriate action under **Actions Assigned to Selected Trigger** column. The action you are looking for is called **Move Left a Space** and **Move Right a Space**, as shown:

[image]

---

#### Gestures defined for Magic Mouse:

[image]

#### Gestures defined for Multi-Touch Trackpad:

[image]